# blank dialogue box without my text nor OK button

Tags: gtk, messagebox

I'm trying to popup an OK message box in my gtk browser, but all I'm getting is blank grey square patch without my text in it and even button is not visible.

PFB the function which I'm using to render message box :

```
Void DisplayOKPopup()
{
    dialogue=gtk_message_dialogue_new(GTK_WINDOW(WebtBrowserWindow),    
    GTK_DIALOGUE_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
    GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
    GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
    "text message");
    gtk_widget_show(dialogue);
    LOGDEBUG(" 1");
    gtk_dialogue_run(GTK_DIALOGUE (dialogue));
    LOGDEBUG("2");
    gtk_widget_destroy (dialogue);
}
```

As per my debug log, I can see that control is passing till `LOGDEBUG("1")` and after that it goes to `gtk_dialogue_run` after that UI is getting crashed, the line next to run i.e `LOGDEBUG("2")` is not getting executed.

Kindly provide your inputs as I'm working on this since 3 days:!

Comment: Hi, the code indentation is not so good. Also gtk_message_dialogue_new and gtk_dialogue_run should be gtk_message_dialog_new and gtk_dialog_run. Is there anything on your side to explain this change?

Comment: I'm sorry, i dint get what u meant.
"Also gtk_message_dialogue_new and gtk_dialogue_run should be gtk_message_dialog_new and gtk_dialog_run"

Comment: Dialogue does not exist, should be dialog

Comment: I'm really sorry that's the typo which i made while posting in this site, in my code i'm using proper spelling "dialog". please let me the know what is the mistake that i'm making and what must be changed. TIA.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this issue..:(

Comment: Can you add more code? Seems ok. Something with the main loop? threads? Difficult to assert the problem. And also, which platform you are on, Gtk version, etc. Try to give us more info.

Comment: We are working on gtkwebkit version 3.
please know that i can not share the main loop of the program due to security issue, the company for which i'm working for.

As dialog box isn't working, i tried implementing an alert box as below :

void CWebkitGTKApp::DisplayOKPopup(const std::string& message)
{
        std::string js="alert('string which i want to display');";
        webkit_web_view_execute_script(gtkWebView,js.c_str());
}

but there is no effect of this on the screen.
please know that my objective is to somehow get a popup box with OK button on it, kindly help me with it.

Comment: My guess is that, somehow, you are messing with threads or with the mainloop. Try to remove the `gtk_dialog_run` and `gtk_widget_destroy` lines just to check if the content of the dialog window is shown.

Comment: Yes, you were right..coz when i try to display popup as separate application, i'm able to see the message box, but when i try to integrate it with browser it is not working.

i tried to call the same dialog from GTKMain thread which works fine, i.e, message box has been displayed..but my requirement is to call that function from memCheck() function which is different thread.

memCheck() : this would consume the memory first, and post that message popup is called, saying "system is going for restart, as memory has been consumed" - with OK button.

please suggest further.

Comment: Notice that Gtk is thread aware but not thread safe. If you are using Gtk code (code that updates the UI) from a thread other than the main thread/mainloop then caution must be used. You can try using gdk thread lock/unlock (mutexes), a simple global var (not very beautiful) or a small message queue (for example, async_queue). Your code is Gtk2 or Gtk3?

Comment: Please know that i have tried using mutex locks while calling a particular function which is supposed to drain the memory and render message popup, but No luck.

Its GTK3 that i'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

As concluded, the problem arises from the use of threads. There are several approaches to solve the issue but since there is not code, I'll try with a simple example so that you can recreate it on your code.

Take a global Boolean variable as a flag and on your thread, set it to true so that a "periodic" idle callback can check it and if the flag is `TRUE` then show the dialog. The logic is that the Gtk UI functions are called from the mainloop/main thread and not from the worker threads.

- `DisplayOkPopup` just has a simple "counter" from 0 to MAX_INT (32 bits) and set's the global flag as TRUE.
- `check_for_dialog` it's a callback that runs on mainloop idle time and check for the flag, if `TRUE` then runs the dialog.
- exit is dirty and will output errors but the goal ain't that, its just a tip/hint for your solution.

**Example:**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean dialog_active;
gboolean show_dialog_popup;
GtkWidget *window;

gpointer DisplayOKPopup (gpointer user_data) {
   int i;

   while (TRUE) {
      for (i = 0; i < G_MAXINT32; i++) {
         // nop
      }

      show_dialog_popup = TRUE; 
   }
   return NULL;
}

gboolean check_for_dialog (gpointer user_data) {
   if (show_dialog_popup == TRUE && dialog_active == FALSE) {
      dialog_active = TRUE;

      GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window),    
      GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
      GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
      GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
      "text message"); 

      gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG (dialog));

      show_dialog_popup = FALSE;
      dialog_active = FALSE;
      gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
   }

   return TRUE;
}

static void app_activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {

   window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window Title Here");
   gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 700, 400);
   gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

   //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);
   gtk_widget_show_all(window);

   g_idle_add(check_for_dialog, NULL);
   g_thread_new("my thread", DisplayOKPopup, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   GtkApplication *app;
   int status;

   show_dialog_popup = FALSE; 
   dialog_active = FALSE;

   app = gtk_application_new("your.application.id", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
   g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(app_activate), NULL);

   status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);

   g_object_unref(app);
   return status;
}
```

**Build and run:**

```
$ gcc -o test test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
$ ./test
```

**Result:**
[image: Result UI]

**EDIT**:

Answer to your comment is:

To have custom buttons on your dialog then use:

1. gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons
2. gtk_dialog_add_button (if dialog exists, will add 1 button)
3. gtk_dialog_add_buttons (same as above but can add many buttons)

Example for 1):

```
dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ("My dialog",
                                      main_app_window,
                                      flags,
                                      "_OK",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                      "_Cancel",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_REJECT,
                                      NULL);
```

Example for 2):

```
gtk_dialog_add_button (GTK_DIALOG(dialog),
                       "This is my button",
                       GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT);
```

Example for 3) is same as 2) but can handle many buttons and terminates with NULL.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jose, i'm able to see message box.

i wanted to change the language of text which is displayed inside the message box which i changed successfully, but now the requirement is i need to even change the language of "OK" on "GTK_BUTTONS_OK".

Can u think of any solution which might be helpful for that?